# fadeIn or fadeOut a css style using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to know if it is possible to `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` some CSS style using jquery

```
$("#id").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $("input[type=text]").css('border','1px solid gray');
    }else{
        $("input[type=text]").css('border','1px solid red'); 
    }
});
```

I need to do something like

```
$("input[type=text]").css('border','1px solid red').fadeOut("slow");
```

But this is not working ...

**Any Suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this simple effect can be done with CSS and only a necessary jQuery. Check this minimal example:

**CSS:**

```
input{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.error{
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#id").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }
});
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/0puu7c2j/